# How to identify xpath for an element which does not have any tag?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I would need to identify one element uniquely.However that element does not have any tag.Could you please help to identify the element uniquely?

```
<div class="mbs2_support ng-binding"><strong>Customer care? </strong>Phone 999 888 777 6</div>
```

Here I need to identify only phone number column without "Customer care" section.
Highlighted one(attached screenshot) I need identify.I have tried following xpath, but it is taking whole row(including customer column)

- `//div[contains(text(), ' Phone 999 888 777 6')]`
- `//div[text()[normalize-space()='Phone 999 888 777 6']]`

[image]

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: @Andersson Java I'm using for my scripting

Answer (score 1):

*"...element does not have any tag"* is not actually correct. Required text node is a child of `div`. You can get it with below JavaScript (using [JavaScriptExecutor](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/javascriptexecutor-selenium-webdriver/)):

```
'return document.querySelector("div.mbs2_support").lastChild.textContent;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the text() *child* of the diff, the text in `<strong>` is a grandchild, so won't be included:

```
//div[contains(., 'Phone ')]/text()
```

Comment: Selenium supports XPath expressions that returns WebElement only!

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to identify is a child `text Node` of the parent `<div>` tag.

As per the *HTML* you have provided to extract the text **Phone 999 888 777 6** you can use the [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method as follows:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mbs2_support ng-binding']"));
String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'mbs2_support')]")); 
String getText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', element).toString();
```

Get the element and parse the string. lastChild in javascript will do the trick: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp